# component’s RTF field are not getting saved properly

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. There is a specific scenario where the updates in the component’s RTF field are not getting saved properly. Below is the HTML snippet that I placed in the RTF field’s source tab.

```
<object id=" TSExperience01" class="Experience">

  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
  <param name="width" value="640"/>
  <param name="height" value="320"/>
  <param name="playerID" value="40011"/>
  <param name="playerKey" value="PZ8kLW34EoAFb911eC53wTSWW"/>
  <param name="isVid" value="true"/>
  <param name="isUI" value="true"/>
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true"/>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
  <param name="seamlessTabbing" value="false"/>
  <param name="swliveconnect" value="true"/>
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
  <param name="quality" value="high"/>
  <param name="secureConnections" value="true"/>
  <param name="secureHTMLConnections" value="true"/>
  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="634401"/>
</object>
```

When I go to Design tab of RTF field and Save the component, the RTF content is getting transformed in below:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://tes.com?&amp;width=640&amp;height=320&amp;flashID=TSExperience01&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;playerID=40011&amp;playerKey=PZ8kLW34EoAFb911eC53wTSWW&amp;isVid=true&amp;isUI=true&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;allowScriptAccess=always&amp;allowFullScreen=true&amp;seamlessTabbing=false&amp;swliveconnect=true&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;quality=high&amp;secureConnections=true&amp;secureHTMLConnections=true&amp;%40videoPlayer=634401&amp;autoStart=&amp;debuggerID=&amp;startTime=1439464692492" id="TSExperience01" width="640" height="320" class="Experience" seamlesstabbing="undefined">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="seamlessTabbing" value="false"/>
<param name="swliveconnect" value="true"/>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
</object>
```

When I access tridion CME using IP address in browser, the above change is working as expected, in other words, what ever content is entered in the source tab of RTF field, that is getting saved as-is. When I access tridion CME using domain name(ex: www.abc.com/SDL), the change is not getting saved properly and is getting converted into un-expected format.

Can someone help here.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is it consistent across browsers?

Comment: I have faced the similar issue a long back while working with videos embedding in RTF field of a component. Finally I had to go with a plain text field for this purpose. 

@Nuno - As far as I remember, I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome browser. When we switch to design tab, the content gets changed automatically.

Comment: Hi Nuno, I have this problem with IE,Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It is strange that using a named url produces different results than going directly to the machine's IP address. Is it possible that the named URL goes via a load balancer or some other/different network node? Could this be stripping the additional content? Are you 100% sure these requests are going to the same machine?